# Error Installing python-pip

Tags: python, installation, pip

after install python-pip using "$ sudo apt-get install python-pip"

when i check version "$ pip -V"

showing error "bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
"

can anyone help please???

thanks.

Comment: Can you try "$ python -V" and show me the output?

Comment: "Python 2.7.12"

Comment: How about "$which -a pip"

Comment: output is "/usr/bin/pip"

Comment: Just in case... What's the output for `ls -la /usr/bin/pip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip
```

It could be one of the following cases or just a broken symlink.

---

My guess: `/usr/local/bin/pip` is probably using Python 3 which is not installed on your system (assuming Ubuntu or Debian). This can be verified by checking the first line of the file:

```
head /usr/local/bin/pip
```

If it shows something like `#!/usr/bin/python3`, and Python 3 is not installed, it could cause the error "No such file or directory".

I asked you to run "which -a pip" is also another way to check this. Since `apt` only installs pip in `/usr/bin` but not `/usr/local/bin`, it probably that you never called the `pip` command installed through `apt`.

However, I can not tell if it's the case until you tried these commands. After that thing becomes really simple: just delete `/usr/local/bin/pip` will fix the problem.

Comment: Python 3 uses "/usr/bin/pip"


head /usr/local/bin/pip shows "No such file or directory".

Comment: Hmm, have you installed pip in other ways, for example https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py?

Comment: head /usr/local/bin/pip shows "No such file or directory": Maybe just open a new console will solve it.

Comment: @TanmoyGhosh Glad to hear. It's better if you can share about how you solved the problem :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to install python-pip from the segment in which python scripts exist.

In my case, you can see in this image: [image]

At the title bar press cmd and hit Enter.
Command prompt will open at this directory.
I am sure your pip is not in Scripts directory, thats why you are facing the same issue I faced some days before.

Try execute the commands :
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Or you can install the updated version pip3

Hope it will work.

Comment: Bash is a Linux/Mac console.

Comment: i am in Ubuntu- 16.04.

and i think you are in windows.

Comment: Yeah!! I am in Windows